# How is this equation justified for a prime counting function?

Tags: analysis

I seem to have trouble with how LHS=RHS. Apologies if this turns out to be too elementary. I found this in the book 'The theory of zeta functions' by E.C Titchmarsh and D.R Heath-Brown

$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\pi(n) \int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{s}{x(x^s -1)}dx=s\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{\pi(x)}{x(x^s -1)}dx$

Here $s$ is a complex number and $\pi(x)$ is a prime counting function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $s$ is a constant in the first integral and can be pulled out.
2. $\pi(n)$ is a constant in the first integral, and can be pulled in.

This gives 
$$
LHS = \sum_{n=2}^\infty s \int_n^{n+1} \frac{\pi(n)}{x(x^s - 1)} dx
$$

I'm assuming that for $x$ not an integer, the authors use $\pi(x)$ to denote $\pi(floor(x))$, so we can replace $\pi(n)$ in the integral from $n$ to $n+1$ with $\pi(x)$, and it'll be wrong only at $x = n+1$, which is a single point and contributes nothing to the integral. So now the LHS is
\begin{align}
LHS 
&= \sum_{n=2}^\infty s \int_n^{n+1} \frac{\pi(x)}{x(x^s - 1)} dx \\
&= s \left( \int_2^{3} \frac{\pi(x)}{x(x^s - 1)} dx 
+ \int_3^{4} \frac{\pi(x)}{x(x^s - 1)} dx 
+ \ldots
\right)
\end{align}

Now write out that sum for the first few values of $n$ as I've done above. There's an integral from $2$ to $3$; an integral from $3$ to $4$, and so on. The integrands are all the same, so you can pull them together into a single integral from $2$ to $\infty$. And you're done...

N.B.: I should be a little clearer about that last step. The left hand side denotes the sum of an infinite series; that sum is *defined* to be the limit of the partial sums. The partial sum of the first $k$ terms is a finite sum of adjacent integrals, and can be converted to something of the form
$$
s \left( \int_2^{3} \frac{\pi(x)}{x(x^s - 1)} dx 
+ \int_3^{4} \frac{\pi(x)}{x(x^s - 1)} dx 
+ \ldots
+ \int_{k+1}^{k+2} \frac{\pi(x)}{x(x^s - 1)} dx 
\right) \\= 
s\int_2^{k+2} \frac{\pi(x)}{x(x^s - 1)} dx 
$$

The limit of this, as $k \to \infty$, is exactly the *definition* of $s \int_2^\infty \ldots$. We can then conclude that these things are equal, provided that we know that either side *converges*. The proof of convergence requires a bit more work, and I don't think it's what was confusing you here, so I'm not going to try to address it.

Comment: $\pi(x)$ part is still confusing me.  Prime counting function itself is discrete, so why does it make sense to skip a value at n+1?

Comment: "I'm assuming that for x not an integer, the authors use π(x) to denote..." No need to assume anything here, the prime counting function is, from the start, defined on the real line, see the first sentence of the page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function (or any other source, really).

Comment: As you can see, the OP doesn't appear to actually understand that aspect of the definition of $\pi$; I wasn't certain whether the definition always used the reals as the domain, or in some places just used the naturals, for instance. Perhaps I should have looked it up. No good deed goes unpunished. :)

Comment: @SehraSahu: Consider $\int_4^5 \pi(x) dx$ vs $\int_4^5 \pi(4) dx$. The integrands differ at exactly one point, namely $x = 5$; but if functions $f$ and $g$ agree except at finitely many points, then $\int_a^b f(x) dx = \int_a^b g(x) dx$ for every $a$ and $b$, an idea that can be informally summed up as "integrals (on the real line) ignore finite sets". So these two integrals are in fact identical. Analogous reasoning applies to the integrals in my answer.

Comment: @JohnHughes, Thank you for the explanation :). I happened to know this, but got confused in this particular case.